# Compact "subsets" in the internal real numbers of a topos

Tags: topos-theory

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a topos with internal (Dedekind?) real numbers $\mathbb{R}_{\mathcal{E}}$. Suppose that $K\subset\mathbb{R}_{\mathcal{E}}$ is a compact "subset" (here, I assume that there is some kind of internal topology on $\mathbb{R}_{\mathcal{E}}$). My question is:

It is true that $K$ has a least member? In other words, is the statement $\exists r\in K (r\leq a\ \forall a\in K)$ true in the internal logic of $\mathcal{E}$?

What would be the meaning of such a thing for a spatial topos?

Comment: Do you know what closed subsets of the reals look like in a spatial topos? Also, someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I assume there are multiple inequivalent definitions of what it means to be a closed set in these situations.

Comment: Yes. Intuitively, because no choice is used in the construction.
One could take compact to mean complete and totally bounded. Here completeness is defined in a choice-free way, avoiding sequences, e.g. using nets or locators.
I'm not sure about the most convenient reference, but I'd start with Fred Richman's work on a choice-free development of metric spaces.

Comment: I see...For instance, in a spatial topos, the real numbers are nothing but the sheaf of continuous functions over the base...this means that there is a continuous function $f\in K$ (I mean, a global section of $K$) so that for any other continuous function $g\in K$, the functional inequality $f\leq g$ holds?